# How do i fix my PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH variables after ruining them?

Tags: python, macos

So my problem is i ruined my python versions whit doing something like :

```
alias python=/Library/Python/2.7 
export PYTHONHOME=[:]
```

I set them in terminal not in code :(

... Can somebody help me fixing them ?

Os : Mac Os x 10.8.4 (Macbook pro)
Python versions : 2.7 , 3.5

Thank you !

Comment: Remove the code where you set those values?

Comment: please, post a complete example.